# kotlin flow using flatmap cannot call method in collect

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    adapter?.getData()?.let {
        val flowable = it.asFlow()
        flowable.onEach {
            doCompress(it)
        }.flatMapConcat {
            flow<Unit> {
                updateProgressInMain()
            }.flowOn(Dispachers.Main)
        }.catch {
            dismissLoading()
        }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect {
            Log.d("Collect", "" + Thread.currentThread())
        }
    }
}
```

As above code, I cannot print 'Collect' log in console but other code can run well. However, I can print the log when I use 'WithContext()' in onEach period instead of flatMapConcat to switch Thread. Could anyone discribe what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You produce an empty Flow that never emits in `flatMapConcat`, so the resulting Flow will never emit anything either.

Your code doesn't quite make sense to me, but supposing the task you want to do is, for each item emitted by the source LiveData as Flow:

- Pass it to `doCompress()` on the IO Dispatcher. Apparently `doCompress()` doesn't return anything.
- Call `updateProgressInMain()` on the main thread after eeach item is compressed.

And then call `dismissLoading()` whether or not it failed.

Then this simpler code should do it:

```
adapter?.getData()?.asFlow()?.onEach {
    runCatching {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            doCompress(it)
            Log.d("Collect", "" + Thread.currentThread())
        }
        updateProgressInMain()
    }
    dismissLoading()
}?.launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: Solved! The problem is just flatMapConcat never emits. Thanks.